# How to get all categories on a category page - category.php - when using multiple categories in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

Hi there hope someone can help.... I've been searhing the internet for hours but can't find this info at all.

When on a category page ie

```
www.yoursite.com/category/uncategorized
```

It is fairly straightforward in the theme file (eg `category.php`)to get the category id of the current category - I can use something like

```
get_query_var( 'cat' )
```

or some other alternative.

BUT

How do I get all the categories (ids, slugs anything!) when using multiple categories on the category page from a URL like:

http://www.yoursite.com/?category_name=category1+category2+category3

The category page itself, only lists the first category name when using multiple categories filters in any theme I've seen and `get_query_var( 'cat' )` returns the first category only.

I do not want to use `$_GET` or `$_REQUEST` on the `category_name` var, for 2 reasons:

1. This is surely the wrong way to do it.
2. I am actually using a URL like this - `www.yoursite.com/category/category1+category2+category3/` (yes this works perfectly and the same way as the first example!)

Thanks for any help in advance, I am completely stuck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching some more I found the answer.  To get the query var as it is in the URL use `$wp_query`, even if the url is rewritten like

```
www.yoursite.com/category/category1+category2+category3/
```

You can still retrieve the category names using:

```
global $wp_query;
$wp_query->query['category_name']
```

For some reason this is different to `get_query_var( 'category_name' )` which only shows the first category out of multiple categories.

:)

Answer (score 0):

This is going to completely depend on what your theme is using for a category page template, as there are multiple ways, and no standard method (from what I understand) of building a category template.

This is the heirachy Wordpress uses when loading a category page:

1. category-slug.php
2. category-ID.php
3. category.php
4. archive.php
5. index.php

Once you find the proper file your theme uses to construct the category page, you will have to see how multiple categories are displayed. This should give you an idea how to pull those IDs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Tim, the problem is, how do I get some sort of list to loop through of all the categories when using multiple categories, in any of those template files...? I am using category.php in this case but it would apply to any theme file.  Thanks

Comment: What type of list do you mean? A list of category IDs, names, or slugs? Or, posts IDs?

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I am after anything, ID's, slugs etc.. have just figured out the answer so posting it now - using wp_query ;) thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

you can go with get_categories($args); function as well where $args will keep your arguments in array ... and it will return array of your categories from their you can use foreach loop to fetch whatever you want like for even better understanding follow this url https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that is a useful function, but the point was to retrieve the list of the *current* categories based on the current archive (URL provided, when multiple categories are being shown) - not just a list of all categories